# Clearing resources on unsubscribe

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am having some trouble with executing some logic when a subscription has been unsubscribed. I've been at this for hours and I have made little progress so far. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class Command<E> {

    public CommandActionObservable execute() {
        final CommandAction<E> command = createCommand();

        final OnSubscribe<CommandAction<E>> onSubscribe = (subscriber) -> {

            /* Create a listener that handles notifications and register it.
             * The idea here is to push the command downstream so it can be re-executed
             */
            final Listener listener = (event) -> {
              subscriber.onNext(command);
            }
            registerListener(listener);

            /* This is where I'm having trouble. The unregister method
             * should be executed when the subscriber unsubscribed, 
             * but it never happens
             */
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                unregisterListener(listener);
            }));

            // pass the initial command downstream
            subscriber.onNext(command);

            kickOffBackgroundAction();             
        }

        final Observable<CommandAction<E>> actionObservable = Observable.create(onSubscribe)
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .observeOn(Shedulers.io())
            .onBackpressureLatest();
        return new CommandActionObservable((subscriber) -> {
            actionObservable.unsafeSubscribe(subscriber);
        })
    }

    public class CommandActionObservable extends Observable<CommandAction<E> {

        // default constructor omitted

        public Observable<E> toResult() {
            return lift((Operator) (subscriber) ->  {
                return new Subscriber<CommandAction<E>>() {
                    // delegate onCompleted and onError to subscriber

                    public void onNext(CommandAction<E> action) {
                        // execute the action and pass the result downstream
                        final E result = action.execute();
                        subscriber.onNext(result)
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am using the `Command` in the usual way, adding the resulting subscription to a `CompositeSubscription` and unsubscribing from it in `onDestroy()`. Here is an example:

```
final Observable<SomeType> obs = new Command<SomeType>()
                                       .execute()
                                       .toResult();
subscription.add(obs.subscribe(// impl here));



public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

As mentioned, I can't get the unsubscription logic to work and unregister the listener, which causes memory leaks in the app. If I call `doOnUnsubscribe()` on `obs` it gets called, so I am unsubscibing correctly, but maybe the nesting of the observables and lifting causes some issues.

I'd be glad to head opinions on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was way easier than I anticipated.

After a bit of digging around I was able to come up with the answer on my own. Just posting this for people that may end up in the same situation as me.

So, as I mentioned in my question, if I added a `doOnSubscribe()` action to the observable I was getting in my `Activity`, it gets notified. Next I tried adding the same action on the inner `Observables` I'm creating in the `execute()` method. They were not getting called. So, I came to the conclusion that the chain was getting broken somewhere between the observable in my activity and the observables I was creating in `execute()`.

The only thing that was happening to the stream was the application of my custom `Operator` implemented in `toResult()`. After a Google search, I came across this excellent article - [Pitfalls of Operator Implementation](http://akarnokd.blogspot.bg/2015/05/pitfalls-of-operator-implementations.html). I was indeed braking the chain in my operator and the upstream observables were not notified of the unsubscription.

After I did what the author advices, all is good. Here is what I needed to do:

```
lift((Operator) (subscriber) -> {
    // connect the upstream and downstream subscribers to keep the chain intact
    new Subscriber<CommandAction<E>>(subscriber) {
        // the implementation is the same
    }
}
```